# Is every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a book that claims this but I think not. For example, the plane $(0,0,1) + s(1,0,0)+t(0,1,0)$ doesn't contain the zero vector so is not a vector space. The definition of isomorphism specified that $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ were vector spaces

Comment: That's correct ! This plane is not a vector space. Is this really what the book exactly claims ?

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath that is a _bijection_ but not an _isomorphism_

Comment: Depends on what sense "isomorphic." Most planes in a vector space are not, in fact, vector subspaces.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, at least I believe so. Verbatim:
Theorem 2. Suppose that $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over the real numbers. $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ are isomorphic if and only if they are of the same dimension.
Examples
a) Every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yeah, it is probably the case that the book is using "plane" to mean "plane through zero" or "$2$-dimensional subspace." But it is sloppy.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah I assumed as much I just wanted to double check I wasn't misunderstanding something along the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends isomorphic **as what**.

Your remark that planes in $\Bbb R^3$ need to contain $(0,0,0)$ in order to be vector spaces is correct. Every plane containing $(0,0,0)$ is indeed a vector space and all of them are isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ **as vector spaces**.

Yet every plane in $\Bbb R^3$ is isomorphic to  $\Bbb R^2$ as **affine space**.